# What is the most efficient and robust way to program ASP.NET with javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I wanted to know what is the best approach to program ASP.NET with JS?
So far, I've been trying to code with the Codebehind attributes.add("onclick," ....");
is there a better more efficient way to use JS with ASP.NET?

thanks

Comment: i think writing your functions in a separate js file is much more efficient and flexible than trying to write all the your javascript functions from code behind.

Comment: But how can I achieve that? I dont know my control's IDs... (ctl100....)

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Do you write custom controls and need them to write some JS to the browser?

Comment: @oshafran - regarding the ID, you can find it by having `this.ClientID` in the control code behind..

Comment: I don't write any controllers. I just want it to be easier to use JS on them. on all events, such as onmousemove... what is the best way to integrate JS & asp.net?

Comment: @oshafran use `<%= myControl.ClientID %>` for those.

Comment: the whole <%= myControl.ClientId %> seems so cumbersome... is this the preferred way to program?

Comment: You could also use ClientIDMode="Static" if you're in .Net 4.0

Comment: But you cann't type in `<%= myControl.ClientId %>` in a separate js file, only in your aspx page

Comment: @thesupertramp - I know... that is why I say its cumbersome

Comment: @SuperTramp - thanks, but I find the ClientIDMode=static more convinenit

Answer (score 3):

writing all your function in a separate js file is far more flexible that what you are doing now. The problem might be getting the control ID's in your js file.
Well there are many methods.

**Hardcoding**

Just view the source and figure out the ID of the control which you want to use.
   this is easy but if you you may want to change  the ID of the control at some point of time the respective functions will not work

**Something like This**

Declare a variable with all the the ClientIDs in the aspx file use it in the js file

```
var MyControlIDs = {"Textbox1":"<%= Textbox1.ClientID %>","Label1":"<%= Label1.ClentID %>"};
```

and in your js file `var mycontrol= window.MyControlIDs`
and use it wherever you want

`var textbox = document.getElementById(mycontrol.TextBox1);`

Answer (score 0):

Many WebControls have an [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) property, which is equivalent of what you're doing. Also you can always set it in your markup for controls that don't have the property.

Comment: thanks. Is this is the best way to use JS & ASP.NET? using this programming method?

Comment: Also, what about other events? like onmousemove?

Comment: @oshafran I can't remember any controls that have an onmousemove property in .NET off the top of my head. Simplest would probably be to use the markup to set it. Otherwise the method you mentioned is the normal way. There are more convoluted ways, including creating your own controls or overriding the render.